# Using Chrome Console to Access Knockout ViewModel with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, google-chrome-devtools

How do I access the KnockOut ViewModel variables in the Chrome console now that I am using RequireJS?

Before using RequireJS, I followed a namespacing pattern, hiding everything within a single global.  I could access the global by typing the following into the Chrome console: window.namespaceVar.

But now that I am using RequireJS, all my variables are hidden behind the require function.

```
require(['knockout-2.2.0', 'jquery'], function (ko, jQuery) {

    var ViewModel = function () {
            var testVar = ko.observable(true);
        };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

So how would I access the current value of `testVar` in the example?

Comment: Well, you can't - the chrome console is not a javascript debugger! But why not use `console.log(testVar);` to check the value of that variable?

Comment: You can use breakpoints in chrome and check the values

Comment: @Niko `testVar` is bound to the function scope and not accesible from outside.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Knockout includes the functions `ko.dataFor` and `ko.contextFor` that will give you access to the KO view model information given an element.

So, in the console, you can do something like:

```
var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body);
```

In your case, `testVar` is not exposed, so you would still not be able to access it.  I assume that yours was just a sample though and you meant something like:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
     this.testVar = ko.observable(true);
};
```

Now, using the above method you would be able to access `vm.testVar` and its value by doing `vm.testVar()`

Here are the docs that we have on these functions: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

and here's a step-by-guide on how to debug KnockoutJS with chrome:
http://devillers.nl/quick-debugging-knockoutjs-in-chrome/

using Chrome's $0_$4 feature: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#0-4

Comment: Ryan, I get 'ReferenceError: ko is not defined' when I type in `var = vm = ko.dataFor(document.body);`

Comment: Ah, if you are loading KO through require.js, then it will not be global either.  Typically I have exposed Knockout globally `window.ko = ko;` to be able to do something like this.

Comment: that's a great work around.  I don't know why I didn't of it earlier!  Thanks!

Comment: If you select an element with Chrome debugger, you can use syntax: ko.dataFor($0) and ko.contextFor($0)  https://devillers.nl/blog/quick-debugging-knockoutjs-in-chrome/

Answer (score 14):

As Ryan suggested, the quickest way is to use `ko.contextFor` and `ko.dataFor` in the console to see the binding context of an element on the dom.

There's also a very useful Chrome Extension that uses this principle called KnockoutJS Context Debugger, available here:

[Chrome Web Store - KnockoutJS Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof)

It allows you to inspect an element and see it's context in the sidebar of the elements pane. It's most useful it you have multiple binding contexts on a page, or very nested binding contexts.

Comment: Crashing Chrome in June 2017

Answer (score 11):

Require is all about not having globals:

```
require(["knockout"],function(ko){ window.ko=ko;});
```

is introducing globals again

You can use this in the console:

```
require("knockout").dataFor($0);
require("knockout").contextFor($0);
```