# Knockout.js, set observable value manually from developer console

Tags: knockout.js

Giving the following setup:

```
<textarea id="textarea-chat" type="text" data-bind="value: chatMessage" />
```

I'd like to open the developer console and manually set the value of chatMessage

```
document.getElementById('textarea-chat').value = 'somevalue';
```

Will change the content of the of the DOM element, but not the observer value.
Accessing `chatMessage()` results in `undefined`

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: hi again.. when we enter a value through the keyboard, the value doesn't update in the observable until we press 'enter' or tab out, or click somewhere else. So you could try simulating a click anywhere on the screen after you send the new value through the console

Comment: @Ray, will try, thanks!!

Comment: @Ray in the scenario of doing something like element.value = "abc" then physicly moving focus and clicking on other elements, from console: the observable still does not have value, unless I will physicly go into the input and hit the keyboard.

Comment: @Ray if you wanna look at the entrie code, that could be arranged :)

Comment: yes, I'd like to :)

Comment: have a look at my answer first? I think it's what you need

Comment: @Ray, thanks, trying now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156209/discussion-between-ray-and-aviran).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310659/using-chrome-console-to-access-knockout-viewmodel-with-requirejs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474185/set-property-value-outside-knockout-view-model-definition), you need to access the value of chatMessage through the ViewModel, which is available in the console when you use the  `ko.dataFor()` method. So, the steps would be:

1. `var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body)`
2. `vm.chatMessage('somevalue')`