# Set value from developer console or using the self-made "button"

Tags: knockout.js

I ran into the problem that I'm incapable to set any value to the field from the developer console (Chrome) or using the self-made "button" in the browser
I used to use that approach:

```
document.getElementById('someId').value = 'someValue';
```

And it worked like the video below:
https://youtu.be/SBTQmDVOpOw?t=14

But currently this approach does not work with Knockout.js

I found the answer in this topic: [Knockout.js, set observable value manually from developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622101/knockout-js-set-observable-value-manually-from-developer-console)
but it does not work in my case. So, I have the following tags:

```
<input class="md-input__textfield" id="parameterName" type="text" name="parameterName" maxlength="100" data-bind="value: parameterName">
```

And I'm trying to do this:

```
var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body);
vm.parameterName('somevalue');
```

And I get the following message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameterName' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:41
```

How can I solve the problem and put the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving the viewmodel knockout bound to `document.body`. The `input` element with the `value` binding probably has a completely different binding context. You should target it directly, e.g.:

```
const vm = ko.dataFor(document.getElementById("parameterName"));
vm.parameterName("someValue");
```